# Set the height of a modal dialog

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to fix the height of a modal dialog.

Fixing the width works, but whatever the height I set, the modal height just fits its content.

Is there a way to set a height even if there is nothing in the body of the modal dialog?

Comment: I suppose you are trying to use percentage values?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Add this css rules to your stylesheet in `.modal-content` and `.modal-dialog` classes

```
.modal-dialog {
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.modal-content{
    height: 100%;
}
```